# Smooth scroll on some tags and not others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my website I have used smooth scrolling which works on the nav bar tags. But I can't get it to work on the tags at the bottom of the page and also on the about us button.

Can anyone suggest how I may do this?

Website:
http://www.wholesalexboxlive.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've targeted your navigation items using ID selector

[image]

So your footer links are not working with the code, either you can remove ID attribute from the top navigation, or you add parent selector in the footer and target it in the code.

[image]

Just like this:

[image]

[image]

I've added a new class in footer links and also registered that class in click event handlers.

Comment: You should't really answer [off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) questions. They are usually eventually closed and deleted, which would be a waste of your time. (Not to mention that it encourages people to ask off-topic questions.) Also please read through [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) meta post about posting code as images. That post is about questions but most of it applies to answers as well. (People can't copy paste it if it helps them.)